# Creating a Chat App in Python on the Client Side but there are several issues that I cannot figure out

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-multithreading

Issue 1:

The socket is closing prematurely.
If the user gives a unique username it accepts it properly.
But if the user gives a username that is already used, the "try again message" is displayed and the user is asked to input a new username BUT since the socket is closing prematurely after the user inputs their new username the "unexpected response from server" message is displayed and then the user is prompted to input a new username again before an error pops up ([Errno 31] broken pipe).

Issue 2:

When a user types in "!who" the list of all currently logged in users is displayed correctly. However, after the list is displayed the user can no longer interact with the server. No error pops up but the server becomes unresponsive.

Issue 3:

After the user types "!quit" nothing happens. But if the user types in "!who" right after the list of all currently logged in users does pop up so this means the user did not actually shut down the client.

Code:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host_port = ("123.37.104.311", 1200)
client_sock.connect(host_port)

# use this to shut down the client???
# def close():
#     server.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
#     server.close()
#     print ("closed")

# request unique username from user

while True:
  user_name = input('Enter a unique user name: ')
  message = 'HELLO-FROM {}\n'.format(user_name)
  client_sock.send(message.encode())
  response = client_sock.recv(4096).decode()

  if response.startswith('HELLO '):
    print('You are logged in as {}'.format(response[6:].strip()))
    break

  elif response == 'IN-USE\n':
    print('That username is already in use. Please input an alternative.')

  elif response == 'BUSY\n':
    print(
      'The maximum number of clients has been reached. Please try again later.'
    )
    sys.exit()

  else:
    print('Unexpected response from server.')

  break

user requests list of all currently logged in users

  while True:
  list_request = input()
  if list_request == '!who':
    message1 = 'LIST\n'
    client_sock.sendall(message1.encode())
    response = client_sock.recv(4096).decode()
    if response.startswith('LIST-OK '):
      print('Here is a list of all currently logged in users: {}'.format(response[8:].strip()))
      break

# user asks to shut down the client

while True:
  quit_request = input()
  if quit_request == '!quit':
    sys.exit()

# while True:
#   shutdown_request = input()
#   if shutdown_request == '!quit':
#     close()
#     exit(0)
#     print('Chat clinet has been shutdown.')

# function recieves messages from other users and displays them to the user

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            # Waiting until data comes in
            # Receive at most 4096 bytes
            data = client_sock.recv(4096).decode()
            if not data:
                    print("Socket is closed.")
            else:
                    print("Socket has data.")
        except OSError as msg:
            print(msg)
            socket.close()
            break

# all possible inputs

# while True:
#   user_input = input(user_name + ': ')

#   if user_input == '!who':
#     message = 'LIST\n'
#     client_sock.sendall(message.encode())
#     response = client_sock.recv(4096).decode()
#     if response.startswith('LIST-OK '):
#       print('Here is a list of all currently logged in users: {}'.format(
#         response[8:].strip()))
#       break

#   if user_input == '!quit':
#     message = shutdown()
#     print('Chat client has been shutdown')
```

Still trying to figure out how to close the client and prevent the socket from shutting down prematurely.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you could produce perhaps a "reproducible" code snippet that leads to this error, that might be helpful for others to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue 1

After all of your if statements, you call break. This exits the while loop. Remove the second break in that while loop like this:

```
while True:
  user_name = input('Enter a unique user name: ')
  message = 'HELLO-FROM {}\n'.format(user_name)
  client_sock.send(message.encode())
  response = client_sock.recv(4096).decode()

  if response.startswith('HELLO '):
    print('You are logged in as {}'.format(response[6:].strip()))
    break

  elif response == 'IN-USE\n':
    print('That username is already in use. Please input an alternative.')

  elif response == 'BUSY\n':
    print(
      'The maximum number of clients has been reached. Please try again later.'
    )
    sys.exit()

  else:
    print('Unexpected response from server.')
```

### Issue 2

I'm going to assume:

```
user requests list of all currently logged in users

  while True:
```

was a formatting error. In which case the while loop falls to the same issue as issue 1:

```
while True:
  list_request = input()
  if list_request == '!who':
    message1 = 'LIST\n'
    client_sock.sendall(message1.encode())
    response = client_sock.recv(4096).decode()
    if response.startswith('LIST-OK '):
      print('Here is a list of all currently logged in users: {}'.format(response[8:].strip()))
```

### Issue 3

The code you have supplied, given that half of it is commented out, does not come to this conclusion. What should happen is that once the user requests the table, and receives it successfully, the while loop is quit starting another while loop that runs until the user asks to quit.

As a general piece of advice, add print statements around your code to figure out where your code is stopping, that way you can find the line of code the computer is stuck on.